# PostGIS unknown projection id in ST_Transform proj4 string

Tags: postgis, proj

Using PostGIS I'm trying to transform a point coordinate from EPSG:31468 to EPSG:4326 using a proj4-string that I obtained from QGIS "Select Datum Transform" (is it one?):

[image]

SQL is of the form `geometry ST_Transform(geometry geom, text to_proj);`:

```
SELECT(ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(4482649, 5485174), 31468), '+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +step +proj=hgridshift +grids=BETA2007.gsb +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg')));
```

As the result I'getting this error:

```
ERROR:  transform_geom: couldn't parse proj4 output string: '+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +step +proj=hgridshift +grids=BETA2007.gsb +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg': unknown projection id
CONTEXT:  SQL function "st_transform" statement 1
```

What's probably wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

What you copied is a whole transformation.

PostGIS wants a CRS definition, not a transformation. It will figure out how to do the transformation between your source CRS and the destination CRS itself.

```
SELECT 
  ST_AsText(
    ST_Transform(
      ST_SetSRID(
        ST_Point(4482649, 5485174), 
        31468
      ), 
      4326
    )
  )
;
```